# Digital Mars DOS _fmalloc not giving pointer to usable memory?

Tags: c, file, malloc, dos

I'm using the Digital Mars C compiler to write a 16-bit DOS program, in the small memory model. This program needs to save a file to the hard disk, and it also needs to allocate 64,000 bytes in memory to temporarily store data in preparation to save it, along with some other data, to the hard disk. The problem is that it was saving gibberish to the file, when it shouldn't be. I made a separate small program so that I could separate my possibly bugged code from code that shouldn't have any problems. So far, I've been able to track the problem down to the `_fmalloc()` function in Digital Mars. When I write data that has been allocated with `_fmalloc()` the data gets corrupted with what seems like program data. When I allocate memory off of the stack, there is no problem and the program works as intended.
.
.

### File Test Program

This is the small program I wrote to eliminate possible problems in my code and figure out where the problem is.

```
#include <io.h>
#include <sys\stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    //unsigned char data[256]; <-- using this way works just fine

    unsigned char __far *data; <-- this way does not work
    data = _fmalloc(256);

    if(data==NULL)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //initialize data to 1
    _fmemset(data, 1, 256);


    int file;   //file handle
    unsigned int err = 0;

    // Create File
    file = _creat("file.bin", _S_IREAD | _S_IWRITE);

    if(file==-1){
        printf("Error creating file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }else{
        printf("File created successfully.\n");
        err = 0;
    }

    // Write Data to File
    int bytes_written = 0;
    bytes_written = _write(file, &data, 256);

    if(bytes_written==-1){
        printf("Error writing to file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }else{
        if(bytes_written == 256){
            printf("File written successfully.\n");
            err = 0;
        }else{
            printf("Error wrong amount of data written.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    // Close File
    err = _close(file);

    if(err==-1){
        printf("Error closing file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }else{
        printf("File closed.\n");
    }

    _ffree(data);

    return 0;
}
```

.
.

### File Output

.
.
Using `data[256];`
*This is what the output should look like. 256 bytes total.*

> 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
>   01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
>   01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
>   01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
>   01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
>   01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
>   01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
>   01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
>   01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
>   01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
>   01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
>   01 01 01

Using `data = _fmalloc(256);`
*NO BUENO! Note that this also produces an extra byte, for a grand total of 257 bytes.*

> 00 00 38 14 00 01 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 E5 02 A2 01 01 00 1F 01 7E
>   2B 43 3A 5C 46 49 4C 45 2E 45 58 45 00 3C 00 50 41 54 48 3D 5A 3A 5C
>   00 43 4F 4D 53 50 45 43 3D 5A 3A 5C 43 4F 4D 4D 41 4E 44 2E 43 4F 4D
>   00 42 4C 41 53 54 45 52 3D 41 32 32 30 20 49 35 20 44 31 20 48 35 20
>   54 36 00 00 0D 0A 00 42 2B 4B 2B 62 2B 00 00 06 09 6A D4 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00

text view

> ..8...........å.¢.....~+C:\FILE.EXE.<.PATH=Z:.COMSPEC=Z:\COMMAND.COM.BLASTER=A220
>   I5 D1 H5
>
> T6.....B+K+b+....jÔ.................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Other than the issue with far vs near pointers, why not just use a more convenient memory model? E.g. Compact or Large?

Comment: Well, I'm doing this for a learning project. I learn a lot of stuff by trying to do these antiquated programming projects. I want to use the small memory model, because it forces me to have to use these _far pointers and mix them with _near pointers and I have limited _near data and etc.. These restrictions teach me a lot of things that I, most likely, would never have to deal with when doing a modern 32/64 bit protected mode project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_write(file, &data, 256)` needs to be `_write(file, data, 256)` for the `malloc` case. It works for the auto allocated case because `data` and `&data` are the same address for arrays (though different types).

Comment: Hmm, you are right when I use malloc, but what about _fmalloc? Do I need a _write() that takes a __far *?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `malloc` vs `fmalloc`. It's standard C. `&data` gives the address of the pointer. But what is needed is the pointer value itself (what `fmalloc` returned).

Comment: No, I undestand that. But _write won't take the pointer when I try to use the __far * version. I'm asking if I just need an entirely different version of _write() in order to use a __far *?

Comment: Ok, that's an entirely different question and is not one I can answer. Ask a seperate question that hopefully someone else can answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up needing a _far version of the _write() and _read() functions. These were not provided with the compiler, so I made my own. Forgive me if these seem a little crude, but I've never done anything like this before, so this was a good learning experience for me. Here is the code I came up with.

```
int _fwrite(int fd, void __far *buffer, unsigned int length)
{
    void *buffer_offset             = 0; // used to pass the offset of buffer to _write()
    unsigned int buffer_segment     = 0; // used to change the value of the data segment register (DS)
    unsigned long int buffer_copy   = 0; // used for temporary, corruptible storage of buffer
    int result                      = 0; // used for returning number of bytes written or an error from _write()

    // store the full __far pointer buffer in buffer_copy as a 32 bit int so that we can use bitwise operators
    buffer_copy   = (unsigned long int)buffer;

    // left shift the address stored in buffer_copy two bytes to get the offset address
    buffer_offset = (void *)(buffer_copy << 16);

    // right shift the address stored in buffer_copy two bytes to get the segment address
    buffer_segment = buffer_copy >> 16;

    // change the data segment register to the one that buffer points to so that _write() will work on far data
    asm
    {
        push ds
        mov ds,buffer_segment
    }

    // do the file write
    result = _write(fd, buffer_offset, length);

    // restore previous data segment register value so that near data can be accessed again
    asm
    {
        pop ds
    }

    return result;
}

int _fread(int fd, void __far *buffer, unsigned int length)
{
    void *buffer_offset             = 0; // used to pass the offset of buffer to _read()
    unsigned int buffer_segment     = 0; // used to change the value of the data segment register (DS)
    unsigned long int buffer_copy   = 0; // used for temporary, corruptible storage of buffer
    int result                      = 0; // used for returning number of bytes written or an error from _read()

    // store the full __far pointer buffer in buffer_copy as a 32 bit int so that we can use bitwise operators
    buffer_copy   = (unsigned long int)buffer;

    // left shift the address stored in buffer_copy two bytes to get the offset address
    buffer_offset = (void *)(buffer_copy << 16);

    // right shift the address stored in buffer_copy two bytes to get the segment address
    buffer_segment = buffer_copy >> 16;

    // change the data segment register to the one that buffer points to so that _read() will work on far data
    asm
    {
        push ds
        mov ds,buffer_segment
    }

    // do the file read
    result = _read(fd, buffer_offset, length);

    // restore previous data segment register value so that near data can be accessed again
    asm
    {
        pop ds
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is bad. You're lucky that it works. Or, perhaps, you haven't yet experienced it fail (what if file I/O fails, did you test that case?). What if `_read()` and `_write()` need to access a global variable, e.g. set `errno` and DS does not point to the default data segment? What if these functions also need ES to point to the default data segment? A much cleaner and safer solution would be to have a small near buffer of, say, 1 KB and use this buffer for file I/O (in 1KB chunks, with all proper error checks) and copy data between this near buffer and the far buffer.

Comment: Eh, well, I have had lots of errors, and none of them result in a crash. I've purposely created file I/O errors, and it seems to work fine. It accesses errno every time this happens as well, but all seems fine. How would you create a far write and read from scratch? I am here to learn, so by all means, teach me!

Comment: You can dereference and increment a pointer (both near and far), right?

Comment: Yes, I don't see any reason why you couldn't.

Comment: With that you can copy between buffers.

Comment: So, you're just saying to create a near buffer and a far buffer, and copy from the far buffer to the near buffer and write out from the near buffer? Like `unsigned char __far *far_data;` `unsigned char *near_data;` `far_data = _fmalloc(64000);` `near_data = malloc(1000);` `_fmemcpy(near_data, far_data, 1000);` `_write(file, near_data, 1000);` and do this as many times as needed until all 64000 bytes are written?